# PHP - array shenanigans

Tags: php

Currently, the code below only returns the first letter of the strings in `$pizzas[]`:

```
$total = 0;
  $pizzas = array('kebabpizza' => 80, 'calzone' => 60, 'vesuvio' => 60);
  foreach ($pizzas as $pizza => $price) {
    for($i = 0; $i < count($pizza); $i ++) {
      echo $pizza[$i] . " - $price<br>";
      break;
    }
    $total +=$price;
  }
  echo "Your order is gonna cost you $total kr<hr>";
```

Output:

```
k - 80
c - 60
v - 60
Your order is gonna cost you 200 kr
```

Comment: Why are you looping over `$pizza` just `echo $pizza` and you will get `kebabpizza`

Comment: You can't count a string: `count($pizza)` -> `Warning: count(): Parameter must be an array or an object that implements Countable`

Comment: Yes, no need for the `for($i = 0; $i < count($pizza); $i ++) {` part

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you do your `foreach` loop, you're iterating over your array. When you say `as $pizza => $price`, the variable `$pizza` is assigned the key of the current array item you're looking at and `$price` is assigned the value. So in the first iteration of the loop `$pizza` is `kebabpizza` and `$price` is `80`.

Next, you're doing a `for` loop over the string `kebabpizza` (or whatever the key of the array is at that time). When you try to access `$pizza[$i]` in the first iteration of the `for` loop you're getting the letter `k` in `kebabpizza`. You're then `echo`ing out `k` and then the price of the pizza.

Following that you have a `break` statement which will terminate the inner `for` loop and the outer `foreach` loop will continue. That's why you're seeing only the first letters.

Assuming you want to output the name of the pizza and the price, then you don't need the inner `for` loop at all:

```
$total = 0;
$pizzas = array('kebabpizza' => 80, 'calzone' => 60, 'vesuvio' => 60);
foreach ($pizzas as $pizza => $price) {
    echo "$pizza - $price<br>";

    $total +=$price;
}

echo "Your order is gonna cost you $total kr<hr>";
```

Answer (score 0):

Why are you looping over `$pizza`

```
$total = 0;
$pizzas = array('kebabpizza' => 80, 'calzone' => 60, 'vesuvio' => 60);

foreach ($pizzas as $pizza => $price) {
    echo $pizza . " - " . $price . "<br>";
    $total +=$price;
}

echo "Your order is gonna cost you $total kr<hr>";
```

Answer (score 0):

Beacuse you are looing in the $pizza variable that is a string(so an array of chars) instead of just using it in the foreach cycle

```
$total = 0;
$pizzas = array('kebabpizza' => 80, 'calzone' => 60, 'vesuvio' => 60);
foreach ($pizzas as $pizza => $price) {
 echo $pizza . " - $price<br>";
}
$total +=$price;

echo "Your order is gonna cost you $total kr<hr>";
```

clear example

```
$total = 0;
$pizzas = array('kebabpizza' => 80, 'calzone' => 60, 'vesuvio' => 60);
foreach ($pizzas as $key => $value) {
 echo $key . " - $value<br>";
}
$total +=$price;

echo "Your order is gonna cost you $total kr<hr>";
```

Answer (score 0):

That's because you're trying to iterate over a string with your second loop.

Your first loop will iterate over each element in the array:

```
foreach ($pizzas as $pizza => $price) { ...
```

Will iterate over these items

```
- kebabpizza => 80
- calzone => 60
- vesuvio => 60
```

In your inner (second) loop (`for($i = 0; $i < count($pizza); $i ++)`), you will then actually try to iterate over each character in the key element

```
k[0]
e[1]
b[2]
a[3]
...
```

If you just skip the inner loop altogether and print `$pizza` instead you should be fine

```
foreach ($pizzas as $pizza => $price) {
    echo $pizza . " - $price<br>";
}
$total +=$price;
```

Answer (score 0):

[`count()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.count.php) on a string always returns 1. What you are looking for is [`strlen()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strlen.php) but it's completely unnecessary. Just `echo $pizza;`.

In fact, if it were to work you'd get something like:

```
k - 80
e - 80
...
```